# How to automaticly delete file from database record when the current row is deleted from table - laravel

Tags: laravel

if I delete a row of Listening_Group, i would like to automaticly delete the file from storage

I already have my own code, but seems like it doesn't work.

```
class Listening_Group extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable =[
        "part",
        "audio_path",
        "id_listening"
    ];

    public function soalListening(){
        return $this->hasMany(Listening_Soal::class, "id_group", "id");
    }

    public function listening(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Listening::class, 'id_listening');
    }

    public static function boot(){
        parent::boot();
        self::deleting(
            function($group){
                if($group->audio_path){
                    unlink(public_path()."/storage/assets/audio/".$group->audio_path);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `audio_path`  and `public_path()."/storage/assets/audio/".$group->audio_path`?

Comment: audio_path is name fo audio file on that location
ex : listening_session_1.mp3
location : public/stograge/assest/audio/

Comment: instead of letting the model delete the file, I would trigger an event (hence dispatching an asynchronous job) to delete the file... Imagine the, for any reason, the deletion fails... it should be done in other place so it does not stop your code... And my personal recommendation, stick to [Laravel's naming convention](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), all your classes and columns are badly named, else it is harder for any dev to follow it at the beginning.

Comment: Ah.. im sorry for that, cos i just changed my plan, originally im using filepath, but so many repetition and i dont like it. So instead of using filepath, using filename for that colum, but i forgot to change the column name. Hehe

Comment: Which part is not working?

Comment: self::deleting()..